# Audio Visualization in React Native

Tags: react-native

Is there any package or utility that enables parsing an mp3/wav in React Native?

I was searching something similar to the function [visualizeAudio](https://www.remotion.dev/docs/visualize-audio) by Remotion.

```js
 import music from "./music.mp3";
 ...

 const audioData = useAudioData(music);

 const visualization = visualizeAudio({
    fps,
    frame,
    audioData,
    numberOfSamples: 16,
  }); // [0.22, 0.1, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Hi @enzo-manuel-mangano, do you find any solutions?